# Semantic UI: Change with for mobile

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I am totaly new to semantic ui and I just cant get this to work or find an answer online:
I have this piece of html I have to work with:

```html
<div class="ui grid stackable">
    <div class="eleven wide">
        <table class="ui table selectable">
              ....
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="four wide column">
       ....
    </div>
</div>
```

The two inner divs are designed for computer and I need to make them responsive.
On Computer, they are side by side but on mobile they should both be sixteen wide and stacked.
I cant figure out, if it is possible to change the width just with semantic Ui classes.
Is there a way to tell the divs `seven wide computer, sixteen wide mobile and tablet`?

EDIT: Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/70L3a9p4/1/
As you can see, the two items are side by side as they should be (on computer)
But on mobile they should both be sixteen wide (or the full with of the container) and not side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries for change width on mobile version or css-framework with this abilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the layout every time you are changing your device, it is better to use media rules.

go on you CSS file and in the end create the following rule:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
//inside here you'll have to declare the rules for your div
  }
}
```